# Resizing image on GPU with opencv produces empty output matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, nvidia

I am running this simple application to perform image resize on GTX1080ti GPU:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/cudaimgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/cudawarping.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::cuda;
static void gpuResize(Mat in, Mat out){
    double k = in.cols/416.;
    cuda::GpuMat gpuInImage;
    cuda::GpuMat gpuOutImage;
    gpuInImage.upload(in);
    const Size2i &newSize = Size(416, in.rows / k);
    cout << "newSize " << newSize<< endl;
    cuda::resize(gpuInImage, gpuOutImage, newSize);
    gpuOutImage.download(out);
}

int main(){
    Mat im = Mat::zeros(Size(832,832),CV_8UC3);
    Mat out;
    if (getCudaEnabledDeviceCount() == 0){
        return cerr << "No GPU found or the library is compiled without CUDA support" << endl, -1;
    }
    cv::cuda::printShortCudaDeviceInfo(cv::cuda::getDevice());
    gpuResize(im,out);
    cout << "real size="<<out.size() <<endl;
}
```

the output I'm getting:

```
Device 0:  "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti"  11177Mb, sm_61, Driver/Runtime ver.10.10/10.10
newSize [416 x 416]
real size=[0 x 0]
```

why output matrix has 0x0 size, how should I fix that?

Comment: should you be passing `out` [by reference](http://zafar.cc/2018/3/7/passing-cv-mat-as-argument/) instead of by value?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem with how you're parsing out into the function. The function would modify its local copy and once your function returns. The original out hasn't been modified. Try parsing by reference.

Comment: Thats the root cause, dear Joshua. But I am a bit confused, I thought that Mat is intended work as shared pointers? When I pass Mat by value, actual pixels are not copied, right? Can you please clarify this in the answer?